# How can we get ERD diagram for all the tables in the database in PLSQL developer?

Tags: sql, database, plsql, plsqldeveloper, ert

I am trying to get ERD diagram for all the tables from my database.. is that possible ? I use PL/sql developer.. want to know if there are any plugins or any way to get the same/

Comment: I think you can use a diagram window (File -> New -> Diagram Window). Then you just drag the tables you want from the object browser into the window.

Comment: ERT seems to be something to do with EMACS. Are you sure you didn't mean ERD? Even then, I wouldn't expect any PL/SQL Developer plugin to do logical modelling. Did you mean a physical data model?

Comment: Sorry, yeah it is ERD.. Thanks for the suggestion@Chrisrs2292 ..I know i can actually drag and drop tables for the ERD but i wanted it for each and every table in my database. something around 2567 records i have in my database... I think that is not possible but just wanna check if there is a way..